# Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

While i'm trying to run this code, this exception " Only parameterless constructors and initializes are supported in LINQ to Entities." was thrown. Can u help me to solve this.

```
        var year = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(318).Year;
        var month = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(318).Month;
        var start = new DateTime();
        if (month >= 4)
        {
            start = new DateTime(year, 04, 01);
        }
        else if (month < 4)
        {
            start = new DateTime(year - 1, 04, 01);
        }
        var qr =  (from h in context.heads
                  join l in context.ledgers.Where(x => x.entry_date >= start && x.entry_date < new DateTime(year, month, 1))
                  on h.h_id equals l.h_id into hl where hl.Any()
                  let totalbalance = hl.Sum(d => d.debit) - hl.Sum(c => c.credit)
                  select new { h.name, totalbalance });
        Repeater2.DataSource = qr.OrderByDescending(x => x.totalbalance).Take(4);
        Repeater2.DataBind();
```

Comment: i'm using the framework 3.5

Comment: on which line did this exception come up?

Comment: Repeater2.DataBind();

Comment: i didn't import the stored procedures and functions. is that a problem for this.?

Comment: Try changing the select part to `select new { Name = h.name, TotalBalance = totalbalance }`

Comment: if i try to import stored procedures and functions it will generate Error 146: Return type is not valid in FunctionImport 'function_name'. The FunctionImport must return a collection of scalar values or a collection of entities.

Comment: i try the select part as you suggested, but it again throws the same exception on the same line.

Comment: i add the tolist() to the query. Now the same exception is generated on this line. var qr =  (from h in context.heads
                      join l in context.ledgers.Where(x => x.entry_date >= start && x.entry_date < new DateTime(year, month, 1))
                      on h.h_id equals l.h_id into hl where hl.Any()
                      let totalbalance = hl.Sum(d => d.debit) - hl.Sum(c => c.credit)
                       select new { Name = h.name, TotalBalance = totalbalance }).ToList();

Comment: One of your entity classes doesn't have a parameterless constructor, either `head` or `ledger`.